# добавить счётчик fps в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Начал создавать игру в pygame. Решил добавить счётчик fps, но у меня ничего не получилось. Нигде в гугле я не нашёл ответа.
Подскажите, как его сделать?

P.S. Я ну очень начинающий программист. Если мой вопрос показался вам тупым, это нормально.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887804/pygame-is-not-displaying-a-grid-or-fps-counter

Answer (score 1):

В pygame есть встроенная функция для получения количества кадров в секунду -

```
clock=pygame.time.Clock() # Создать объект Clock (Требуется только один раз в коде!)
print(clock.get_fps()) # Вывести в консоль fps (Должно быть внутри вашего цикла)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный способ:

```py
    import time
    while True:
        start_time = time.time() # start time of the loop

    print("FPS: ", 1.0 / (time.time() - start_time))
```

Или:

```py
import time

start_time = time.time()
x = 1 # displays the frame rate every 1 second
counter = 0
while True:
    counter+=1
    if (time.time() - start_time) > x :
        print("FPS: ", counter / (time.time() - start_time))
        counter = 0
        start_time = time.time()
```